# Sorting List Items by First Letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort list items by their first letter. I am filtering by the .list-title div and then showing the .list-item which holds all of the contents. The problem is, I am using the show method directly on the filter method which is causing nothing to show as it needs to show the .list-item (parent) for the returned results. I am not sure how to rewrite this in any other way. How can I show the list item for each item returned?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function filterResults(letter){
        $('.list-item').hide();
        $('li.list-item .list-title').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() === letter;
        }).show();
    };
    filterResults('A');
    $('a').on('click',function(){
        var letter = $(this).text();            
        filterResults(letter);        
    });
});

var $listItem =  $('.list-item')
$('a').addClass(function(){
    var s = this.textContent;
    return $listItem.filter(function(){
       return this.textContent.charAt(0) === s
           }).length ? '' : 'grey';
})
```

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2ewgr2mt/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hide `.list-item` at first which contains everything else.So, when you show `.list-title` it won't be shown because its parent (`.list-item`) is hidden. The correct code should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterResults(letter){
    $('.list-item').hide();
    $('.list-item').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.list-title').text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() === letter;
    }).show();
  };

  filterResults('A');
  $('a').on('click',function(){
    var letter = $(this).text();      
    filterResults(letter);        
  });

  var $listItem =  $('.list-item')
  $('a').addClass(function(){
    var s = this.textContent;
    return $listItem.filter(function(){
       return this.textContent.charAt(0) === s
           }).length ? '' : 'grey';
  });
});
```

P/s: Remember to put everything inside `ready`, and also be careful when using the selector, in your original code you missed `.` in front of the class name selectors

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much. I've updated the code with the proper selector syntax for future visitors of this question.